# Buildfire: use buildfire.navigation.navigateTo (pluginData)

Tags: java, html, buildfire

I'm trying to write a second menu to the home folder plugin and I want to write a piece of html in the text block (between the carrousel block and the Plugin Instances) so the user can navigate to another plugins.

How can I use the `buildfire.navigation.navigateTo (pluginData)` function there? How can I write the function using the `<a href=""></a>`?

Where are the `pluginData` that the function needs? 
- `pluginId`
- `instanceId`
- `folderName`
- `title`

Because when I'm trying to use it (I'm trying the `navigateHome();` function to make sure it works), I get an Access Denied error.

Right now I'm trying this:

```
<a onclick="javascript:buildfire.navigation.navigateHome();">
```

and it doesn't work.

How can I navigate to another plugins?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation on Navigation https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation

Fundamentally `javascript:buildfire.navigation.navigateHome()` should work. Please post the error you receive so we may review it.

Navigating to another plugin can be done with
`buildfire.navigation.navigateTo (pluginData)`

```
pluginData {
    pluginId: (string) The id of the plugin type you'd like to navigate to.
    ,instanceId: (string) The the instance of the plugin you'd like to navigate to.
    ,folderName (string) The folder name of the plugin that you'd like to navigate to.
    ,title (string) The title that should show up in the title bar once the plugin is loaded.
    ,queryString (string) Optional. This is a query string that will be passed to the next plugin's window.location.search. example: "name=Larry&age=36&showDetails=true"
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationnavigateto-plugindata

You also should take a look at Dynamic Data to make sure you have the latest references to the plugin as they may change

Ref: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-the-Datastore-Dynamic-Data

All this being said, I'd like to draw your attention to `ActionItems` which are currently implemented in your carousel

[image]

[image]

Ref: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/BuildFire-Action-Items-Component